# How to find elapsed time interval

Tags: c++-cli

```
void Wait(Single wait_time)
{
    Single start_time;
    Single end_time;
    Single ellapsed_time;

    ellapsed_time = 0;
    start_time = DateTime.Now.Second;
    while (ellapsed_time<=wait_time)
    {
        end_time = DateTime.Now.Second;
        ellapsed_time = end_time - start_time;
    }
}
```

The code above is in C# and it works according to my colleague. The goal is to tell the machine to wait for a certain time, then continue after that. For example, when `Wait(5)` is triggered, the machine won't continue until elapsed time is greater than 5.  I'm trying to do the same thing in C++/CLI. Here is my code :

```
void Wait(Single wait_time) 
{
    Single start_time;
    Single end_time;
    Single ellapsed_time;


    ellapsed_time = 0;
    start_time = DateTime::Now;

    while (ellapsed_time <= wait_time) {
        end_time = DateTime::Now;
        ellapsed_time = end_time - start_time;

    }


}
```

I get this error:

> no suitable conversion function from `System::DateTime` to `float` exists

I tried `TimeSpan` as well, but it didn't work. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Ðаn Is there a way to subtract or calculate the difference of two datetime values in c++/cli ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++/CLI

```
using namespace System::Threading;

void wait(int seconds)
{
    //1000 miliseconds = 1 second 
    Thread::Sleep(seconds * 1000);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "test1" << std::endl;
    wait(5);  // wait for 5 secs
    std::cout << "test2" << std::endl;
}
```

Side note, you wouldn't want to waste precious CPU cycles going through a redundant loop. Give it a break!

Comment: @Kaan Agac I'm building it in C++/CLI which is different from C++. This wouldn't work. I tried it out, and it gave me error too.

Comment: @eString please try the edited version, I've managed to run this in C++/CLI. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

C#

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

C++

```
 #include <chrono>
 #include <thread>

 int main() {
 using namespace std::this_thread;
 using namespace std::chrono;
 sleep_until(system_clock::now() + seconds(5));
 }
```

The above code will make your application sleep for 5 seconds.

Or i have seen people use

```
 Thread::Sleep(100);
```

In terms of CLI .

Comment: Much better than a CPU hogging loop IMHO.

Comment: Do note that there is also [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

Comment: @fluffy Since this is for C++/CLI windforms application, I have to put the code within  " public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form { public: } "  instead of inside " int main() { }"  
 I don't think this method works for my application.
 I tried to put the code inside the back ticks but it didn't work for some reasons.